# Si tengo 2 json, como podria mostrar por consola los valores que no son iguales?

Tags: javascript

```
const salesSaved = require("./savedSales.json");
const deals = require("./deals.json");

for (const sale of salesSaved) {
    const element = deals.find((x) => x.DealID !== sale.pipedriveID);
    console.log(element);
}
```

Quiero mostrar por consola los valores de deals que no se encuentran en salesSaved. A continuacion se muestran los json.

Deals.json

```
[
 {
   "DealID": 8020
 },
 {
   "DealID": 8012
 },
 {
   "DealID": 8009
 }
]
```

salesSaved.json

```
[
    {
        "pipedriveID": 285,
        "leadID": 16622,
        "saleID": 3330
    },
    {
        "pipedriveID": 288,
        "leadID": 16623,
        "saleID": 3331
    }
]
```

Se muestran pocos datos en los json solo para ejemplo...
*DealID tiene los mismos valores que pipedriveID* por eso se debe comparar entre ellos.

Comment: ¿Y como son estos json?  ¿Puedes ponerlos en la pregunta?  Puedes pulsar el enlace [edit] que aparece en el pie de la pregunta para modificarla

Comment: Ya los agregue...

Answer (score 2):

Podrías filtrar solo los elementos de `deals` que no esten en el filtro de los elementos de `salesSaved` se interceptan, así:

```js
const salesSaved = require("./savedSales.json");
const deals = require("./deals.json");

const elements = deals.filter(deal => !salesSaved.filter(sale => deal.DealID == sale.pipedriveID).length);

console.log(elements);
```

```html
<!-- require function simulation -->
<script>
  const require = (key) => {
    return {
      "./savedSales.json": [{pipedriveID: 1}, {pipedriveID: 2}, {pipedriveID: 3}],
      "./deals.json": [{DealID: 2},{DealID: 3},{DealID: 4},]
    }[key]
  }
</script>
```

> Note que se esta simulando la data de `./salesSaved.json` y `./deals.json` basado en la comparación realizada en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Mira si esto te sirve:

```js
const deals = [{
    "DealID": 8020
  },
  {
    "DealID": 8012
  },
  {
    "DealID": 8009
  }
]


const salesSaved = [{
    "pipedriveID": 8012,
    "leadID": 16622,
    "saleID": 3330
  },
  {
    "pipedriveID": 288,
    "leadID": 16623,
    "saleID": 3331
  }
]

no_estan = []
for (const deal of deals) {
  const check = salesSaved.some(item => item.pipedriveID === deal.DealID);
  if (!check) {
    no_estan.push(deal.DealID)
  }
}

console.log(no_estan)
```

Como lo que pretendemos es verificar los valores de **deals** lo que hacemos es recorrerlos (y no los otros), y en cada ciclo comprobar mediante el método [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) si se encuentra lo que buscas en el array **salesSaved**, pues devuelve un booleano, y si es así lo agregamos a una variable de array que he denominado `no_estan` que al salir del bucle muestro con el console.log.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono!

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro, recuerda aceptar la respuesta para que no quede pendiente para siempre y la comunidad lo sepa. En [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) aprenderás a aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante hacerlo

Comment: @Javi mírate la respuesta de NeKoOs la cual funciona bastante bien y en una linea lo resuelves, y acepta la que prefieras o te ha sido más útil